# What vampire has the longest existence?

Tags: vampire

I wanted to ask what the life span of a vampire was, but as undead that did not seem like the right question.

What vampire has the longest existence?

Comment: In written fiction, or including movies/TV?

Comment: Written, but if you want to include movies/TV in your answer, I am fine with that.

Comment: This question would be far easier to answer if you could define the scope -- are you talking about a specific fictional universe?  If not, can you EXCLUDE any, or quantify what you are defining as a vampire?  (I.e., is the Stainless Steel Leech considered one?  How about Marvel's Vampires?  Psychic ones?  Blood Mages? etc. [This TVTropes Article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurVampiresAreDifferent) may help. **WARNING** You may lose hours of otherwise productive time if you visit TVTropes...)

Comment: I'd say to improve this question and stop it from being closed, specify the acceptable mediums in the question. ALso -lot's of different media label "vampire" in different ways (Dracula has some very different qualities to a Buffy Turok-han vampire!), so it woul help to provide a basic list of characteristics that allows something to qualify as a vampire - aka "drinks blood using fangs, burns in the sun" and so on. *Something* to narrow the range of possible candidates.

Comment: @DavidS I accepted the answer by iayork, it seems like a reasonable answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Anita Blake: Vampire Detective](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49083-anita-blake-vampire-hunter) novel [Circus of the Damned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_of_the_Damned), one character is ["Mr. Oliver"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampire_Council_of_Anita_Blake:_Vampire_Hunter#Mr_Oliver). He is proposed to be a *Homo erectus* vampire, over a million years old.

Answer (score 0):

In *Blade III*, vampires awakened the progenitor vampire, who lacked some of the weaknesses of common vampires of the present day (he could walk in daylight, for instance, without being the kind of hybrid the Daywalker, Blade, was).  He had been *sleeping* for, as I recall, about four thousand years, and had walked for heaven only knows how long before that.

In written fiction, the longest I'm aware of is the Fred Saberhagen version of Dracula, born as a "breather" in the 14th century and still walking in the late 20th (likely still out there in the 21st).  He, too, could withstand weak winter daylight by the 19th century, albeit with the temporary loss of most of his vampiric abilities.